# Buscar registro usando vba un formulario de Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de vba, con macros en acces, lo que trato de hacer es que al ingresar el ID este realice la consulta correspondiente y muestre uno de los campos en otro cuadro de texto, adjunto la imagen del formulario y del código

Sin embargo al hacer clic en buscar, se muestra lo siguiente. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si uso un id mu largo me arroja el siguiente error 
 se ha producido el error 6 en tiempo de ejecución: Desbordamiento

este es el código que estoy usando

```
   Private Sub consultar_Click()

 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim ValCustID As Integer

 ValCustID = Me.idx.Value

 strSQL = "SELECT Modelo " & "FROM Motores " & "WHERE id='" & ValCustID & "';"

Modelox.Value = strSQL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin tener la información suficiente de la tabla, es probable que el campo `id` sea numérico. Sí el campo es long, deberías mantener los datos en el rango entre -2.147.483.648 y 2.147.483.647.

Viendo que en la consulta se están buscando como texto, también eliminaría las comillas de la consulta:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Modelo FROM Motores WHERE id = " & ValCustID & ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

El error de **desbordamiento** es porque estás asignandole un valor a una variable fuera de sus limites (integer es numerico por tal significa que le asignas un valor superior o inferior al soportado).

Es importante consultar la documentacion para determinar el tipo de variable a utilizar en el proyecto.

Si unicamente vas a manejar numeros, utiliza el tipo `Long` o `Double` para ampliar el rango.

Toma en cuenta si vas a manejar solo enteros, o cifras con decimales.

Answer (score 0):

En estos casos a mi me gusta utilizar recordsets, ya que no se esta utilizando algun cuadro combinado/comboBox, por consiguiente yo lo haria de la siguiente forma:

```
Dim Rs As New ADOB.RecordSet

''Validamos si el campo del Id  no este vacio, si lo esta avizamos al usuario.
If Nz(Me.Idx, "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Aqui se le hace saber al usuario que el campo no esta lleno.", 
           vbInformation + vbOkOnly, "Campo Vacio"
    Exit Sub/Function
End If

''Aqui abrimos el Recordset
With Rs
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentPrject.Connection
    .Open("SELECT Modelo FROM Motores WHERE Id = '" & Nz(Me.Idx, "") & "' ")

    ''En este punto, estamos evaluando que la propiedad EOF (End Of File) _
      no este establecida como true, de estarlo significa que el recordset _
      no tiene ningun dato, o que la consulta no regreso algo.
    If .EOF Then
        MsgBox "No se ha encontrado informacion con ese Id.", vbExclamation + 
               vbOkOnly, "Error!"
        Exit Sub/Function
    ENd If

    ''Si la EOF es falso, es decir que si encontro algo, en este punto es donde _
      seteamos el valor al campo en el que lo queremos.
    Me.Modelo = Nz(!Modelo, "")

End With
```

De esta forma aseguras una buena ejecucion del codigo, un poco mas explicado:

-Nz(): esta funcion sinifica Not Zero, se utiliza para evaluar un control o variable, segun su tipo de dato, por ejemplo, si es numerico de cualquier tipo se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
Nz(ValorNumerico, 0)
```

En caso de se un valor alfanumerico o de cadena:

```
Nz(Cadena, "")
```

Se pone 0 o "" por que es el valor que retornara en caso de que la variable/control venga nulo, y es un dato que se debe de colocar obligatoriamente.

-RecordSet: es un objeto de manipulacion de datos, es decir, por lo general se utilizan para una consulta de SQL, ello conlleva la declaracion de una variable para que funcione, se puede hacer de dos maneras:

```
Dim RsEjemplo As New ADOB.RecordSet
```

ó

```
Dim RsEjemplo As RecordSet
Set RsEjemplo = New ADOB.RecordSet
```

-Clausule With - End With: Este es un metodo de manipulacion de objetos, como puedes notar se utiliza en el objeto RecordSet, este metodo solo simplifica la forma de manipular el objeto, se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
With OjbetoEjemplo
''Para sacar las propiedades del objeto, se referencian con un . seguido de la _
  propiedad.
    .Open
    .Connection
End With
```

Sin mas que compartir, espero haber ayudado.